# use postgresql image with icu collation in circieci (cimg/postgresql, rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, circleci, postgresql-11

I am using [cimg/postgres](https://circleci.com/developer/images/image/cimg/postgres) as my database image.

```
  - image: cimg/postgres:11.12
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
      POSTGRES_DB: XXXX
      POSTGRES_USER: XXXX
```

Then I'd like to use [icu collation](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/icu-support-postgresql-10/), so I specified in my `database.yml`

```
  adapter: postgresql
  ctype: ja-x-icu
  collation: ja-x-icu
```

I ran ci with this setting, but the error occurs as below;

```
PG::WrongObjectType: ERROR:  invalid locale name: "ja-x-icu"
```

I thought that icu collation is available in `cimg/postgres` becuase `--with-icu` is written in the Dockerfile, but actually it does not work.
https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/cimg-postgres/blob/main/15.0/Dockerfile#L68

Question:
・How can I use icu collation with cimg/postgres (in my rails application)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use ICU collations as database or cluster collations in PostgreSQL versions before v15.

Comment: thanks! then, can I use icu collation with the image `cimg/postgres:15.0`? I still get the same error:  `invalid locale name: "ja-x-icu"` when I use it.

Comment: Perhaps PostgreSQL was built without ICU support? Try to create a container with the `C` locale, connect to it and query `pg_collation`.

Comment: thanks! I checked pg_collation by running `SELECT * FROM pg_collation` and ja-x-icu does exist.

Comment: No idea then. Perhaps you should get the exact `initdb` command that is being run and add it to the question.