# Can I create database with icu collation in postges in 2022?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I would like to use icu collation in PostgreSQL with rails application.
I specified icu collation at database.yml like this,

```
  adapter: postgresql
  ctype: ja-x-icu
  collation: ja-x-icu
```

but I got the following error:

```
Caused by:
PG::WrongObjectType: ERROR:  invalid locale name: "ja-x-icu"
```

I found some questions which said that we cannot use icu collation in "CREATE DATABASE".
[Get und-x-icu as collation and character type in Postgres 10 and win server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54411729/get-und-x-icu-as-collation-and-character-type-in-postgres-10-and-win-server-2008)

Is this situation still the same as this question now?
If so, how can I create database with icu collation?

Thank you in advance.
(I'm using Rails 7 and Postgres 11 but I can move to further version if necessary.)

Comment: This is supported since Postgres 15

Comment: Postgres 11 is almost 5 years old at this point. Move on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use postgresql image with icu collation in circieci (cimg/postgresql, rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74846348/use-postgresql-image-with-icu-collation-in-circieci-cimg-postgresql-rails)

Comment: Oh, thanks! Now I got the picture. But still, although I started to use cimg/postgres:15 (which is circleci image for postgres 15), I got the same error about icu collation. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 3):

That is only supported with PostgreSQL v15 or better.

If you are using v15 or better, I guess your mistake is that you simply used

```bash
initdb --encoding=UTF8 --locale=ja-x-icu datadir
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "laurenz".
This user must also own the server process.

initdb: error: invalid locale name "ja-x-icu"
```

You have to do that differently:

```bash
initdb --encoding=UTF8 \
   --locale-provider=icu --locale=ja_JP.utf8 --icu-locale=ja-x-icu datadir
```

Use `--locale` for the C library locale. Even if you are using an ICU collation (`--icu-locale=ja-x-icu --locale-provider=icu`), you have to specify a C library locale as well.